# How to spoof an external advice's Mac address on OS high Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, mac-address, adaptor

I used a [Dell Adapter DA200](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-hdmi-vga-ethernet-usb-30-da200/apd/470-abqn/pc-accessories) for my MacBook Pro to connect the internet in my company because there is no Ethernet port on MBP. However, only devices with specific MAC address(I have it) are allowed to connect the net.

I tried to spoof the MAC address as methods [1](https://blog.macsales.com/43777-tech-101-spoofing-a-mac-address-in-macos-high-sierra),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601846/how-to-spoof-an-ethernet-mac-address-of-the-wired-ethernet-interface-coming-with) but failed. In fact, these methods was OK to spoof my mbp's own MAC address. Exactly, there are several ports as the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjFbF.png) shows. en1 and en2 is mbp's own port's name, and en9(USB 10/100/1000 LAN) is DA200's name. I can spoof the MAC address the en0(wifi's name), en1 etc., but I can't spoof the en9.

Can somebody tell me how to spoof it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a Chinese forum: before spoof DA200's MAC address, the driver of its chip should be installed. The information about the chip can be got at System report -> Hardware -> USB. For DA200, it is Realtek 0x8153. Its driver can be downloaded in Realtek's official site.

Comment: This driver can't work anymore after macOS Big Sur. Unless you turn off SIP.